# Evaluate area of the field defined by $\left (\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2 \right )^2=x^2+y^2$

Tags: integration

> Evaluate the area of the field defined by $\left (\frac {x^2}{4}+y^2 \right )^2=x^2+y^2$

I tried to turn it into a function $y(x)$, bus I was unable to do it. Is it actually possible to solve it explicitly?

Comment: Have you tried polar coordinates?

Comment: That's not an area. It defines some curves. You should use $<$ or/and $>$ to be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Polar coordinates are a good choice in order to find the area enclosed by the peanut-shaped region given by your equation:

[image: The peanut]

By setting $x=\rho\cos\theta$ and $y=\rho\sin\theta $ we have:

$$ A = 32\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(5-3\cos(2\theta))^2} = 5\,\pi.$$

Also notice that your peanut-curve is an [epitrochoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitrochoid).

Answer (score 0):

It is a quadratic in $y^2$ because $(y^2)^2+(\frac{x^2}{2}-1)y^2+(\frac{x^4}{16}-x^2)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
We'll calculate the area $\ds{{\cal A}}$ of the region defined by
$$
{\cal A}\equiv
\braces{\pars{x,y} \in {\mathbb R}^{2}\ \mid\ x^{2} + y^{2} > \pars{{x^{2} \over 4} + y^{2}}^2}
$$

> It's equivalent to:
>   \begin{align}{\cal A}&\equiv\color{#66f}{\large\iint_{{\mathbb R}^{2}}
> \Theta\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} - \bracks{{x^{2} \over 4} + y^{2}}^2}\,\dd x\,\dd y}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{r^{2}
> -\bracks{{1 \over 4}\,r^{2}\cos^{2}\pars{\phi} + r^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\phi}}^{2}}
> r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \Theta\pars{16 -r^{2}\bracks{-3\cos^{2}\pars{\phi} + 4}^{2}}r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \Theta\pars{{4 \over 4 - 3\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}} - r}r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{4\bracks{4 - 3\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}^{-1}}
> r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi
> =8\ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\dd\phi \over \bracks{4 - 3\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}^{2}}}_{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{{5 \over 8}\,\pi}}}
> =\color{#66f}{\Large 5\pi} \approx {\tt 15.7080}
> \end{align}